# Gif doesn't appear with QMovie

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, gif, qmovie

I'm currently working with PyQt5 with the widget QMovie, and I'm trying to display a loading gif whenever I'm doing something that requires a bit of time. The problem is, nothing shows up when i'm generating my loading gif and I'm not sure why even though I've kept my code simple. This is what I've done so far:

```
def loadGif(self):
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 400, 168, 41))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.movie = QtGui.QMovie("assets/loader.gif")
    if(self.movie.isValid()):
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
    else:
        print("FAIL")
```

The path of the gif seems fine (it never goes in the else case). Am I missing something ?
Thank you.

Edit:

This is my gif :  [image]

Comment: The code appears to be fine... Can you upload the gif?

Comment: change `assets/loader.gif` to fullpath and provide a [mre]

Comment: call `self.label.show()`

Comment: YES ! The self.label.show worked . Thank you very much !